# Java 8 - Trying to convert String to LocalDateTime

Tags: date, java-8

I am trying to convert the below `String` to `LocalDateTime`, but somehow its not working.

```
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
val dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2016-09-21 13:43:27.000", formatter);
```

It seems there is a problem in Pattern.

Comment: This isn't really a duplicate of the nominated question. The nominated question wants java.util.Date, and this wants java.time.LocalDateTime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a problem with your *pattern*. You should use 'H' for hours (0-23). The type for `formatter` and `dateTime` is wrong.

This would work correctly:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2016-09-21 13:43:27.000", formatter);
```